# How to switch Service Account over multiple users

Tags: c#, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I'm successfully using service accounts for domain-wide authority to access users' drive files and calendars as follows:

```
ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer initializer =
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = serviceAccountScope,
        User = "user1@myDomain.com"
    }.FromCertificate(certificate);

ServiceAccountCredential credential = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer);

service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
    ApplicationName = appName,
});
```

However, I'm not entirely sure the best way to change users, especially if I'm dealing with many users at once. Is it best to just start over and create a new initializer and service for each user? Or is it possible to keep the same service and just update the imitated user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way ServiceAccountCredential was designed is that it's thread safe, so you can't change the User data. However, we may change the current getter property User to be similar [Token](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth.DotNet4/OAuth2/ServiceAccountCredential.cs#178) (in the way that we look when getting and setting it). Please feel free to open a new issue in our [issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/list) and elaborate more.

For now, you should use a new service and for each "user", as following:

```
ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer initializer =
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(serviceAccountEmail)
    {
        Scopes = serviceAccountScope,
        User = "user1@myDomain.com"
    }.FromCertificate(certificate);

var service1 = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer),
    ApplicationName = appName,
});

initializer.User = "user2@myDomain.com"
var service2 = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
{
    HttpClientInitializer = new ServiceAccountCredential(initializer),`
    ApplicationName = appName,
});
```